# Get data from an API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this from an API:

> {"coord":{"lon":26.1,"lat":44.44},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":27.98,"pressure":1011,"humidity":30,"temp_min":27,"temp_max":29},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1.5,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1535128200,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5986,"message":0.0256,"country":"RO","sunrise":1535081370,"sunset":1535130317},"id":683506,"name":"Bucharest","cod":200}

How can I get the humidity?

Here is my function which doesn't work:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Slatina,ro&appid=b877cc138ceeb7015615b7b122be7958&units=metric", function(result){
document.getElementById("vremeaText").innerHTML = result.weather[0].humidity;
```

Comment: Try `result.main.humidity`

Comment: `const obj = {"coord":{"lon":26.1,"lat":44.44},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":27.98,"pressure":1011,"humidity":30,"temp_min":27,"temp_max":29},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1.5,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1535128200,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5986,"message":0.0256,"country":"RO","sunrise":1535081370,"sunset":1535130317},"id":683506,"name":"Bucharest","cod":200}
console.log(obj.main.humidity);`

Comment: I didn't know that API, it's amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
result.main.humidity;
```

Instead of:

```
result.weather[0].humidity;
```

I suggest you use [JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to make it easier for you to see the actual of a JSON object.

Comment: thanks, actually the json formatter is very helpful for me

Comment: @ProdanMihai If your question is answered, would you mind marking the most relevant answer in this thread as accepted.